# How to connect to firebase using nodejs for crud?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a connection to my firebase host and have one endpoint to post data to user collections however i am stuck at one of the error when i am importing firbase module into my main file , please help where i am making the mistake.

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import {bodyParser} from "body-parser"
const app = express(),
      port = 3080;
import firebase_db from 'firebase';
const fireStore = firebase_db.firestore();
// place holder for the data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../my-app/out')));
process.setMaxListeners(0);
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/api/user", addUser);
const addUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log("Adding new user");
    const data = req.body;
    await fireStore.collection("Users").doc().set(data);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Record saved successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
// router.post("/api/users", getAllUsers)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on the port::${port}`);
});
```

firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {

};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebase_db = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(db);

module.exports = firebase_db;
```

Error

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /Users/node_modules/firebase/package.json imported from /Users/nextjs-nodejs-example/api/server.js
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:285:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:508:3)
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:639:14)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:691:18)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:805:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:72:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:71:36) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is that you are trying to use the Firebase JS SDK in a Node.js environment. If you would like to access Firebase services from your Express server, you should use the Firebase Admin SDK instead. See the [Admin SDK docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for more instructions.

For example:

```
// server.js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {
  getFirestore,
  initializeFirestore,
} from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {...};
const app = admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
initializeFirestore(app);

...
await getFirestore().collection("Users").doc().set(data);
...
```